# How do I get a computer's name and IP address using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

How can i get ip address of system by sending mac ip address as input using vb.net coding?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the My Class :)

```
My.Computer.Name
```

as for the IP address quick google search

```
Private Sub GetIPAddress()

Dim strHostName As String

Dim strIPAddress As String



strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()

strIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()


MessageBox.Show("Host Name: " & strHostName & "; IP Address: " & strIPAddress)

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are using VB.Net 2.0 or better you should be able to use it out of the box :)

Comment: Since `GetHostByName()` is deprecated and gives you a warning in vb.net, you might wanna simply replace it with `GetHostEntry()` which does the same, but makes the compiler happy. Eg: `strIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()`

Comment: Also obviously this gives you only the first IP, if you want to loop through all addresses it is quite easy as well: `For Each adr In System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName).AddressList()` and in the loop you simply check/print/whatever `adr.ToString()`

Comment: This anwser won't work for everyone, it works sometimes because there is only 1 item in the AddressList. When there are many, most often the first few are not IPV4 addresses. The right way would be GetIPv4Address() from EagleEye's answer. The loop will find the IPv4 address wherever it is in the list.

Answer (score 25):

```
Private Function GetIPv4Address() As String
    GetIPv4Address = String.Empty
    Dim strHostName As String = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
    Dim iphe As System.Net.IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName)

    For Each ipheal As System.Net.IPAddress In iphe.AddressList
        If ipheal.AddressFamily = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
            GetIPv4Address = ipheal.ToString()
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: This is the right way to get the IPv4 address. In my log here there are 4 different strings in the AddressList and 3 of them are useless. You have to loop and compare them all to find which one is the IPv4.

Comment: What about if there are multiple IPv4 addresses?

Comment: If someone is on multiple networks (e.g. a LAN and a VPN) they will have multiple IPv4Address. If you're not sure which one you'll want, best to get all of them and let the caller decide which one(s) they need.

Answer (score 4):

Here is Example for this.
In this example we can get IP address of our given host name.

```
   Dim strHostName As String = "jayeshsorathia.blogspot.com"
    'string strHostName = "www.microsoft.com";
    ' Get DNS entry of specified host name
    Dim addresses As IPAddress() = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName).AddressList

    ' The DNS entry may contains more than one IP addresses.
    ' Iterate them and display each along with the type of address (AddressFamily).
    For Each address As IPAddress In addresses
        Response.Write(String.Format("{0} = {1} ({2})", strHostName, address, address.AddressFamily))
        Response.Write("<br/><br/>")
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Shuwaiee

I made a slight change though as using it in a `Private Sub` already.

```
Dim GetIPAddress()

Dim strHostName As String

Dim strIPAddress As String

strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()

strIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()

MessageBox.Show("Host Name: " & strHostName & vbCrLf & "IP Address: " & strIPAddress)
```

But also made a change to the way the details are displayed so that they can show on seperate lines using `& vbCrLf &`

```
MessageBox.Show("Host Name: " & strHostName & vbCrLf & "IP Address: " & strIPAddress)
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Shows the Computer Name, Use a Button to call it

> Dim strHostName As String
>
> ```
>     strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName().
>
>     MsgBox(strHostName)
> ```

Shows the User Name, Use a Button to call it

> If TypeOf My.User.CurrentPrincipal Is Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal Then
>
> ```
>         Dim parts() As String = Split(My.User.Name, "\")
>
>         Dim username As String = parts(1)
>
>         MsgBox(username)
>
>    End If
> ```

For IP Address its little complicated, But I try to explain as much as I can.
First write the next code, before Form1_Load but after import section

> Public Class Form1
>
> ```
> Dim mem As String
>
> Private Sub GetIPAddress()
>
>     Dim strHostName As String
>     Dim strIPAddress As String
>     strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
>     strIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()
>
>     mem = strIPAddress
>     MessageBox.Show("IP Address: " & strIPAddress)
>
> End Sub
> ```

Then in Form1_Load Section just call it

> GetIPAddress()

Result: On form load it will show a msgbox along with the IP address, for put into Label1.text or some where else play with the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ipAddress As IPAddress
Dim ipHostInfo As IPHostEntry = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName())
ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Net

Module MainLine
    Sub Main()
        Dim hostName As String = Dns.GetHostName
        Console.WriteLine("Host Name : " & hostName & vbNewLine)
        For Each address In Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName).AddressList()
            Select Case Convert.ToInt32(address.AddressFamily)
                Case 2
                    Console.WriteLine("IP Version 4 Address: " & address.ToString)
                Case 23
                    Console.WriteLine("IP Version 6 Address: " & address.ToString)
            End Select
        Next
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

IP Version 4 Only ...

```
Imports System.Net

Module MainLine
    Sub Main()
        Dim hostName As String = Dns.GetHostName
        Console.WriteLine("Host Name: " & hostName & vbNewLine)
        Console.WriteLine("IP Version 4 Address(es):")
        For Each address In Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName).AddressList().
            Where(Function(p) p.AddressFamily = Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            Console.WriteLine(vbTab & address.ToString)
        Next
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Label12.Text = "My ID : " + System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList(0).ToString()
```

use this code, without any variable

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of MS Visual Studio for VB.NET, one should use the method `GetHostEntry()`:

```
Dim HostName = "N/A"
Dim ipAddress = "N/A"
Dim ipHostInfo As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())
HostName = Dns.GetHostName()
ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList(1).ToString()
```

Now, keep in mind that `AddressList(0)` is the `::1` network address, which we want to skip and use the second address in the list. Of course, without hardware network card the second element in the list will be absent, so you have to perform additional check in order to avoid `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score -2):

```
    Public strHostName As String
    Public strIPAddress As String
    strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
    strIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()
    MessageBox.Show("Host Name: " & strHostName & "; IP Address: " & strIPAddress)
```