# Return IP address using computer name over local network with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, networking, ip-address

I know the name of the computer on the local network. Is there a way to return the IP address of that computer?

Comment: The [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234757/how-do-i-get-a-computers-name-and-ip-address-using-vb-net) is similar and provides the answer. BTW, first result from google when I used your question! -1

Comment: @Steve Well I had already looked over the link you provided and the answers weren't working. I was able to adjust those answers to come up with the correct solution though. 

System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("hostname-here").AddressList(1).ToString

thanks for the -1 anyhow

Comment: That is EXACTLY what that post was telling you to do. What did you adjust, the variable names? Good work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple answer to my question:

ipaddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("hostname-here").AddressList(1).ToString