# How do I get the computer's IP in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm working at a server chat application and I need to get the ip of the computer that's running the server app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a computer's name and IP address using VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234757/how-do-i-get-a-computers-name-and-ip-address-using-vb-net)

Comment: Yeah, but I've noticed something like ".AddressList(0)" and I was wondering if that wasn't refering to the router that the computer is connected to. As far as I'm concerned the computer might be connected to another port of that router.

Comment: Look at the answer from [EagleEyes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9948132/1070452) note that sometimes what will work best for *you* will not always be accepted answer for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't specify if you want an IPv4 or an IPv6 address:

```
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim networkInterfaces As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        For Each networkInterface As NetworkInterface In networkInterfaces
            For Each unicastAddress As UnicastIPAddressInformation In networkInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
                Console.WriteLine(unicastAddress.Address)
            Next
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

As you iterate through the available network interfaces on the computer, there should be something you would know that would identify the one that you want.

Answer (score -1):

Open cmd and type *ipconfig*. Now look for *IPv4*

Comment: The OP asked how to obtain the IP programmatically using VB.NET and not the OS software.