# Getting the correct IPv4 in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ip, ipv4

i have a problem whit trying to get the correct IPv4 of a machine in VB.Net, i have this code:

```
 Private Function GetIPv4Address() As String
    GetIPv4Address = String.Empty
    Dim HostName As String = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
    Dim ip As System.Net.IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(HostName)

    For Each iph As System.Net.IPAddress In ip.AddressList
        If iph.AddressFamily = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
            GetIPv4Address = iph.ToString()
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

This works very well on a machine who has a single IP attached, but when i try to use this code on a machine with more than 1 IP this gave me the first regardless of which is my main IP.

To be more clear:
If my IP is 192.168.1.15, and i have added (for external things connection purposes) 192.168.1.14 and 192.168.1.200, the code always gave me 192.168.1.14.

How can i fix this?
This code is supposed to run on several different machines with many IP attached.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Which is *the correct IPv4 of a machine*?

Comment: In the exsample i wrote, .15

Comment: Yes, sure. But what makes `192.168.1.15` the *correct* one?

Comment: Is just an exsample, on my machine i have different number, like 29, 32.
The correct one is .15 just because is the one of the computer, the others are added just for external connections purposes, didn't get the question

Comment: If you add an IP address to a Network interface, this IP is *one of the computer*, too. What elements should discriminate one IP from the other, defining one of them as *the right one*? For your purposes, I mean.

Comment: get this now, is "the correct one" cause is the one i gave to that machine, if i have to connect throught TCP to a machine i use the IP address, but with different IPs for connection, i can't connect to the others, cause there are other things connected like sensors and i can't risk to interfiere.
Just like that, i have to use the one i gave (or the DHCP gave him) not the one i'm adding for other sensor's connections

Comment: So, do these additional IP addresses have an assigned DNS address (which is not a local server address)? If they don't, you have your answer. If you think to apply any logic to a generic scenario, you have to take into consideration the routing tables and see which route is the one you care about.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is right here, you just need to cycle through the list of addresses

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11860141/1066191

Comment: Can you help me understand better?
I saw some samples there but don't know what you are referencing