# Get local IP address (IPV4) in VB.NET - error "Resolve is obsoleted for this type" newer version

Tags: vb.net

I have code here that shows the IP address of a host, but it gives me an error. How can I fix this?

And get rid of the *Resolve is obsoleted for this type* thingy.

#### Error message

```
Description
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  Public Shared Overloads Function Resolve(hostName As String)
  As IPHostEntry' is obsolete:

  Resolve is obsoleted for this type. Please use GetHostEntry instead.

  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202'


Severity  Code     Project           Line  Suppression  State
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Warning   BC40000  UltimateDiskless  270                Active

File
-----
C:\Users\Jadam\Desktop\Ultimate Diskless\UltimateDiskless\UltimateDiskless\PacketScanner\frmMain.vb
```

#### Code

```
    Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim hosts() As IPAddress = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList <==**This One Has The error**

        Dim i As Integer

        If hosts.Length = 0 Then Throw New NotSupportedException("This computer does not have non-loopback interfaces installed!")
        For i = 0 To hosts.Length - 1
            MonitorMenuItem.MenuItems.Add(hosts(i).ToString(), New EventHandler(AddressOf Me.OnHostsClick))
            HostsMenu.MenuItems.Add(hosts(i).ToString(), New EventHandler(AddressOf Me.OnHostsClick))
        Next

        ReDim m_PacketMonitors(HostsMenu.MenuItems.Count - 1)

        For i = 0 To m_PacketMonitors.Length - 1
            m_PacketMonitors(i) = New Monitor(hosts(i))
            AddHandler m_PacketMonitors(i).NewPacket, AddressOf Me.OnNewPacket
        Next
        m_Packets = New ArrayList

    End Sub
```

Comment: As the error suggests, you should be using `Dns.GetHostEntry` instead of `Dns.Resolve` - have you tried using that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a computer's name and IP address using VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234757/how-do-i-get-a-computers-name-and-ip-address-using-vb-net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error in this case is clearly telling you how to resolve this:

> Resolve is obsoleted for this type, please use GetHostEntry instead

However, as you actually want the IP addresses, the correct way of getting this is now using `Dns.GetHostAddresses`:

```
Dim hosts() As IPAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())
```

The documentation for `GetHostAddresses` is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses?view=netframework-4.8).

**Edit following OP comment regarding IPv4 Addresses only**

You can use the results in `hosts()` to find IPv4 addresses using code such as:

```
For Each address As IPAddress In hosts
    If address.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
        Console.WriteLine($"{address} is IPv4")
    End If
Next
```

`AddressFamily` is int the `System.Net.Sockets` namespace (in case you haven't already imported it).

Comment: Thanks but this also shows the ipv6 maybe you have a code that only shows the ipv4 

Thank You So Much

Comment: @Jadam You didn't mention in your question needing only IPv4 addresses.  However, I've edited the question to help you filter out what you want

Comment: yeah i kinda forgot that one hehe, thanks so much <3 <3 <3

Comment: @Jadam I've updated it now, and you should see how to obtain IPv4 addresses

Comment: @Jadam The best way to thank someone on Stack Overflow is to accept their answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.

Answer (score -3):

You are receiving an error due to using an obsolete function. Please refer to newer documentation to find the newer way.

Comment: With no solution offered, this would be far better as a comment than an answer

Comment: unable to comment on his post.

Comment: If you are unable to comment then provide an actual answer - you've only added noise.